# Prism JS line number misaligned in Chrome

Tags: syntaxhighlighter, prismjs

I'm using Prism Js to highlight code, but line numbers are not aligend properly in Chrome in some cases. However it works perfectly in Firefox. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Please post the minimal reproducible problem here, so that we can help you!

Comment: This is happening in multiple places. I think this is a known problem in prismjs. I've tried solution provided in other answers in stackoverlfow but it didn't work.

Comment: If its known issue then you should try to find in the github issues of prism js repo

Answer (score 0):

You solve this using external CDN. Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.min.css"/>
```

and

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
```

on top of your default prism.